# Explanation of a code

Tags: python, functional-programming, composite

```
def compose(f, g):
    return lambda x:f(g(x))

def thrice(f):
    return compose(f, compose(f, f))

add1 = lambda x: x + 1


print(thrice(thrice)(add1)(6)) = 33
```

Can anyone explain to me why is this 33?
which side of the composite function should i start reading?

Comment: Can you explain the assignment in the last line?

Comment: This becomes a *huge* stack expansion..

Comment: The function `thrice(thrice)` takes a function and returns the same function composited 3^3=27 times. Hence, `thrice(thrice)(add1)` is a function that adds 27 to its input. Calling it with 6 returns 33.

Comment: I understand. So we should start reading from the left?

Answer (score 1):

1) In terms of math, `compose(f, g) = f ∘ g`

2) Then `thrice(f) = f ∘ f ∘ f`.

3) Then `T := thrice(thrice) = thrice ∘ thrice ∘ thrice`

4) Then `T(f) = f ∘ f ∘ f ∘ f ∘ f ∘ ...` # 27 times

5) Then `thrice(thrice)(add1) = T(add1) = add1 ∘ add1 ∘ ...` # 27 times

6) Then `thrice(thrice(add1))(x) = x + 27`

Answer (score 0):

First call of thrice(thrice) reuturns a function. To that function you pass add1 function and as a result you will again get a function. If you pass 6 to that function you will get 33 as result.

```
f1 = thrice(thrice)
f2 = f1(add1)
print(f2(6))
```